# Association loop returning all attributes of a Model instead of just one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Working with two models: Casts and Lessons. Cast has many Lessons and Lesson belong to Cast.

I'm trying to loop the content of Lessons within a Cast view with:

```
  <%= @cast.lessons.each do |lesson| %>
      <%= lesson.title %>
  <% end %>
```

But the view returns/renders all the attributes of each Lesson instead of just the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equals sign in the loop definition specifies that the output of that line if code should be rendered. 
Try this :

```
  <% @cast.lessons.each do |lesson| %>
      <%= lesson.title %>
  <% end %>
```